Does nginx adhere to semantic versioning?
I did not find any official source clearly saying that nginx's versioning adheres to Semantic Versioning.
Pls provide a proving source for your answer.
Basically, I want to know if I can change the minor version without having breaking changes, but again, didn't find any clear source saying so...

like many RFCs semver seems to be a back derivation from common practice

Sry, I didn't understand that part "back derivation from common practice". I looked up "back derivation" and it says "process or result of creating a new word", but not sure what this has todo with "common practice". Could you elaborate...

read "describing" it as a synonym for "describing" above.

Nginx never followed semantic versioning. It uses old linux kernel versioning where odd version numbers are "unstable" and even versions are "stable".
So the only promise is that changes in "stable" version are non-breaking.
But, to be fair, I've never seen hard breaking changes in nginx. Yes, it sometimes changes defaults, so it potentially could cause unexpected behavior.
In essence, you should read changelog to decide if it safe to upgrade and change your configuration accordingly.

Thanks, do you have any reference for that, or is it more "experience" that this is the case?

I just know. This version system was long before semantic version.

@goulashsoup but you could also ask in nginx's mailing list https://mailman.nginx.org/mailman/listinfo/nginx

k, thanks, for now, I'm gonna trust you on that...
